# Emmet in vs code Polyglot Notebooks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, emmet

Has anyone managed to get emmet working in polyglot notebook HTML cells in Visual Studio Code?

According to the following issue, you should be able to edit the settings for emmet and it will be enabled:
https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/issues/2278

Like so:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "dotnet-interactive.html": "html"
  },
```

However, this does not work for me. I still do not get the emmet tooltip, and pressing enter or tab does not expand the shorthand into full HTML as it should. It works fine in a normal HTML document in VS Code.

I do find that very few of the supported languages seem to give me intellisense prompts in the polyglot notebooks, so maybe this is symptomatic of another problem.